# How do I wire up the Firefox Plug-in Options button?

Tags: firefox, plugins, callback

In Firefox, if you go to Tools -> Add-ons, in the list of extensions each one has an "Options" button.  I would like to enable this for my extension and navigate the browser to a webpage where they can set options relating to my extension.  The extension is an XPCOM extension, so if I can just register for a callback when the button is pressed, that would be ideal.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options (or preferences) button in the Firefox add-ons window is controlled by the `<em:optionsURL/>` tag (or the `em:optionsURL` attribute in `<RDF:description/>`) in the extension's install.rdf.

There is more information about `em:optionsURL` at developer.mozilla.org:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#optionsURL
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_preferences_to_an_extension

Comment: Thank's a lot; I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.rdf
......
<em:optionsType>3</em:optionsType>
<em:optionsURL>resource://@UserAgentChanger/options.htm</em:optionsURL>
......
```